# replace only first occurrence of a word

Tags: jquery, loops, replace

I have a list of Words. If one of these words appears in the document, then the match needs to be replaced with a link. So far i've got this working but the script replaces all occurrences. How can i prevent this by stopping the loop when the first word got replaced and continue with the next term?

EDIT: embedded the code in a snippet:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  
    function replaceWordsWithLinks(_glossaryWords, _language) {

    $.each(_glossaryWords, function (index, wordobject) {
      console.log(wordobject.name);

      var link = '<a class="link link--glossary" title="Open Glossary" data-glossaryid="' + wordobject.link_id + '" data-language="' + _language + '">' + wordobject.name + '</a>';

      $('p').html(function () {
        if (!$(this).parents('.glossary-no-replace').length) {
          return $(this).one().html().replace(wordobject.name, link);
        }
      });
      $('span').html(function () {
        if (!$(this).hasClass('glossary-no-replace') || !$(this).parent().attr('class') == 'breadcrumb' || !$(this).parent().attr('class') == 'glossary-no-replace') {
          return $(this).html().replace(wordobject.name, link);
        }
      });
      $('dd').html(function () {
        if ($(this).parent().attr('class') !== 'glossary-no-replace') {
          return $(this).html().replace(wordobject.name, link);
        }
      });

    });

  }

  var glossary_entries = null;
  var $glossaryElement = $('#glossary-element');

  glossary_entries = $glossaryElement.data('elements');
  var current_glossary_language = null;
  current_glossary_language = $glossaryElement.data('language');

  if (glossary_entries !== null) {
    $glossaryElement.remove();
    replaceWordsWithLinks(glossary_entries, current_glossary_language);
  }
  
})
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
}

body {
  padding: 50px;
}

p {
  max-width: 700px;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  font: normal 18px/1.5 serif;
}
p + p {
  margin-top: 30px;
}

.link {
  color: #bf6a40;
}
.link:hover {
  color: #40bf80;
}

.link--glossary {
  cursor: help;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<p>lorem dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
<p>lorem dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
<p>lorem dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
<div><div class="hidden" id="glossary-element" data-elements='{"1":{"name":"ipsum","link_id":1007},"2":{"name":"lorem","link_id":1006},"3":{"name":"amet","link_id":1005},"4":{"name":"sea","link_id":1005},"5":{"name":"takimata sanctus","link_id":1005}}'></div></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would filter down the  each tag that matches `:contains` selector. If you find matches in a tag ignore the other tags. Then use `first()` to isolate first instance of matching collection

Something like:

```
var $el;

var $pHasWord =
  $('p').not('.glossary-no-replace')
        .filter(':contains(' + wordobject.name + ')');      

if ($pHasWord.length) {
  $el = $pHasWord;

} else {

  var $spanHasWord =
    $('span').not('.glossary-no-replace, .breadcrumb span')
             .filter(':contains(' + wordobject.name + ')');

  if ($spanHasWord.length) {
    $el = $spanHasWord;
  } else {

    $el =
      $('dd').not('.glossary-no-replace dd')
             .filter(':contains(' + wordobject.name + ')');
  }
}

if ($el) {
  $el.first().html(function(_, existHtml) {
    return existHtml.replace(wordobject.name, link);
  });
}
```

Comment: Wow this works like expected! Can you tell me why you used the two parameters and why there is an underscore?  I'd like to better understand the steps of this code. Thank you

Comment: `html(function)` ... first argument is `index` of matching elements instance ( like in `each`) ...second is the existing html. Since need the second argument I just used `_` as a placeholder for the index. it is a valid variable name

Comment: Could also remove all the `.first()` duplication calls and do it once at the end `$el.first().html(_, exist...`